# how to fetch large number of data through multi joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to fetch record which is more than 20k and is coming from around 12 tables.
I am using Datatables jquery plugin for server side pagination. Every time when I reload page or jump to the another page it takes 25 sec  which is so weird. Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `bp` 
left join 
    pdbp on bp.id = pdbp.bp_id 
left join 
    cities on pdbp.city = cities.CityId 
left join 
    regions on pdbp.region = regions.RegionId 
left join 
    countries on pdbp.country = countries.CountryId  
left join (
     SELECT 
         bid, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(subc_name SEPARATOR ', ') as cat 
     FROM 
         sub_categories sc 
     left join 
         `bp_categories` bc on sc.subc_cod = bc.subc_cod group by bid
     ) categories on bp.id = categories.bid 
left join (
     SELECT 
         bid as mbid, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(material SEPARATOR ', ') as mat 
     FROM 
         product_material pm 
     left join 
         `bp_materials` bm on pm.material_cod = bm.mat_cod group by bid 
) materials on bp.id = materials.mbid
left join (
    SELECT 
        bid as cbid, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(description SEPARATOR ', ') as crts from cert ct 
    left join 
        `bp_certificate` bct on ct.id = bct.cid group by cbid
    ) certificate on bp.id = certificate.cbid
```

I really need to make it fast and it is consuming me. any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Do an `explain select`, and post your results here.

Comment: I suggest you don't  `select *` just select the columns you need.

Comment: i did it but it did not make any major effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Make use of views table.

```
CREATE 
    VIEW `sample_view` 
    AS
(
SELECT * FROM `bp` LEFT JOIN pdbp ON bp.id = pdbp.bp_id 
LEFT JOIN cities ON pdbp.city = cities.CityId 
LEFT JOIN regions ON pdbp.region = regions.RegionId 
LEFT JOIN countries ON pdbp.country = countries.CountryId  
LEFT JOIN(SELECT bid, GROUP_CONCAT(subc_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS cat FROM sub_categories sc 
LEFT JOIN `bp_categories` bc ON sc.subc_cod = bc.subc_cod GROUP BY bid) categories ON bp.id = categories.bid 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bid AS mbid, GROUP_CONCAT(material SEPARATOR ', ') AS mat FROM product_material pm 
LEFT JOIN `bp_materials` bm ON pm.material_cod = bm.mat_cod GROUP BY bid ) materials ON bp.id = materials.mbid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bid AS cbid, GROUP_CONCAT(description SEPARATOR ', ') AS crts FROM cert ct 
LEFT JOIN `bp_certificate` bct ON ct.id = bct.cid GROUP BY cbid ) certificate ON bp.id = certificate.cbid  
);
```

Try to run in your side.
Then fetch the view table with limitation for pagination. As for the frontend, the execution time is limited and more than 1000 records will exhaust the memory.

```
select * from sample_view limit 0, 20
```

(2) Avoid unnecessary columns in SELECT clause.
Specify the columns in the SELECT clause instead of using SELECT *. The unnecessary columns places extra loads on the database, which slows down not just the single SQL, but the whole system.

(3) Nested queries can slow the performance. Try to left join all the nested query directly to the main sql query. You didn't tell us your database diagram so I can't provide you sql statement.

(4) Index all the predicates in JOIN, WHERE, ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses.depends heavily on indexes to improve SQL performance and scalability.
Use

```
SELECT EXPLAIN
```

to optimize your query. Check this link to understand explain function

[https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/](http://%20https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)

(5) The ORDER BY clause is mandatory in SQL if the sorted result set is expected.
Be aware of the performance impact of adding the ORDER BY clause, as the database needs to sort the result set, resulting in one of the most expensive operations in SQL execution.

Comment: I think we can discount point 1. MySQL is very poor when it comes to working with views, and besides, LIMIT without ORDER BY is meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes. It is poor yet it has everything. To have better performance is to work with indexing columns, and you are right, use limit and order by clauses.

Comment: I am using datatables jquery server side pagination. Even then I have to use limit ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many approaches

- user server-side pagination with the data table and fetch like 10 to 20 records

if it has been disabled as this simply reduces the amount of data to be displayed. Beyond that, the method you are using for loading the data will typically have the most significant impact on performance.

```
Client-side processing - DOM sourced data: ~5'000 rows. Speed options: orderClasses.

Client-side processing - Ajax sourced data (ajax): ~50'000 rows. Speed options: deferRender
```

`Server-side processing (serverSide): millions of rows.`

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that will affect the performance on your query.

I believe if you are using the DataTables plugin, for example, you must know exactly which fields you want to output.

- Add the proper fields fields to the `SELECT` instead of the `*`
- Consider using inner joins whenever would be possible
- Paginate it from the back-end using the limit and offset
- Cache results...